# Can i implement a Pause and Resume function to my Slideshow Javascript?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am having a Javascript Slideshow. I need to implement a Pause and Resume button on my slideshow where in the slideshow is Paused when i click the Pause Button and when i click Resume Button, the slideshow should resume from where it stopped. This is the script below:

```js
var Pic = new Array();
Pic[0] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002200.jpg'
Pic[1] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002300.jpg'
Pic[2] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002400.jpg'
Pic[3] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002500.jpg'
Pic[4] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002600.jpg'
Pic[5] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002700.jpg'
Pic[6] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002800.jpg'
Pic[7] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3002900.jpg'
Pic[8] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3003000.jpg'
Pic[9] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3003100.jpg'
Pic[10] = 'https://loremflickr.com/320/240?ch01_3003200.jpg'

//this part in real code is replaced with a PHP script that print image location dynamically
var t;
var j = 0;
var p = Pic.length;
var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
  preLoad[i] = new Image();
  preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];
}
//all images are loaded on client
index = 0;

function update() {
  if (preLoad[index] != null) {
    document.images['foto'].src = preLoad[index].src;
    index++;
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
  }
}
update();
```

```html
<div ALIGN="center">
  <img name="foto">
</div>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="resume">Resume</button>
```

Comment: you have no code that uses those buttons? Naming them "pause" and "resume" is not enough, they have to do something, which you would code.

Comment: @Yogi, sure i will check this tutorial. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove the timeout and use setInterval instead
2. clearInterval to stop/pause
3. toggle to pause/resume

```js
var Pic = new Array();
Pic[0] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002200.jpg'
Pic[1] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002300.jpg'
Pic[2] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002400.jpg'
Pic[3] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002500.jpg'
Pic[4] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002600.jpg'
Pic[5] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002700.jpg'
Pic[6] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002800.jpg'
Pic[7] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003002900.jpg'
Pic[8] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003003000.jpg'
Pic[9] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003003100.jpg'
Pic[10] = '../uploads/callmesid/Cam-1/ch01_00000000003003200.jpg'
//this part in real code is replaced with a PHP script that print image location dynamically
var t;
var j = 0;
var p = Pic.length;
var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
  preLoad[i] = new Image();
  preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];
}
//all images are loaded on client
var index = 0;
var length = Pic.length;
function update() {
  if (preLoad[index]) {
    document.images['foto'].src = preLoad[index].src;
    index++;
  }
}
function init() {
  // this resumes from where the index is. If you want to reset, we need more code
  clearInterval(t);
  t = setInterval(update,1000); 
}
function toggle(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
  if (tgt) {
    const pause = tgt.textContent === "Pause";
    if (pause) {
      clearInterval(t)
      tgt.textContent = "Resume";
    }  
    else {
      init(); 
      tgt.textContent = "Pause";      
    } 
  }  
}
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', toggle);
update();
init()
```

```html
<div ALIGN="center">
  <img name="foto">
</div>
<button id="toggle">Pause</button>
```

To add a wrap to my code change to
var length = Pic.length;
function update() {
var currentIndex = index%length;
if (preLoad[currentIndex]) {
document.images['foto'].src = preLoad[currentIndex].src;
index++;
}
}

Comment: i found a small issue with this. The slideshow is not stopping once the array of images is finished. Its on a loop, the slideshow is again continuing from the beginning.

Comment: That would be explained by `I added a wrap to your code (index%length)` - I think he did that for the demo - just use `index` instead of `currentIndex` and remove the reference to `currentIndex` - it's not hard to spot since he mentions it in the answer

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, It is rare to see a slider that does not wrap. I have updated the code and explained how to wrap at the end

Comment: @mplungjan, Thank you so much for the updation.

Comment: A doubt again, is there a way i can have a toggle button, that is when its in Pause mode then only Pause button it should show and when its in Resume Mode then only Resume button it should show. Do you want me to ask as a separate question. Am very new to Javascript so these doubts.

Comment: Normally yes, but I added your update.

Comment: @mplungjan, Thank you so much for this outstanding support.

Comment: Your are welcome. Please note that Stackoverflow does expect some code that shows what you tried yourself. And there are a lot of similar questions that are quite easy to find. I answered because the solutions you would have found likely would be much more complicated than what I posted.